# Laravel Как передать класс в шапку сайта

Tags: php, laravel

Прочел что это нужно делать через View Composer
Создал папку в `ViewComposers` в директории `App\Http` там создал файл `UserinfoComposer.php` с таким содержимым:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Auth;

class UserinfoComposer {
    
    public function compose(View $view) {

        if( Auth::user() ){

            $user_data = array(
                "username"      => Auth::user()['name'],
                "logout_link"   => route('logout'),
            );

            return $view->with('userinfo', $user_data);

        }
    }
}
```

Далее я создал свой провайдер командой:

```
php artisan make:provider ComposerServiceProvider
```

После я сразу добавил его в массив `providers` файла конфигурации `config/app.php` вот так:

```
'providers' => [

...

/*
* Application Service Providers...
*/
...

App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,

],
```

А вот содержимое файла `ComposerServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Http\ViewComposers\UserinfoComposers;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('inc.header', UserinfoComposer::class);
    }
}
```

При запуске сайта получаю такую ошибку от Laravel

```
Target class [App\Providers\UserinfoComposer] does not exist.
(View: /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

Вот сам файл `app.blade.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>@yield('title-block')</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        @include('inc.header')


        <main class="site-main">
            @yield('content')
        </main>

        @include('inc.footer')

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас опечатка в строке `use App\Http\ViewComposers\UserinfoComposers` лишняя **'s'** на конце **UserinfoComposers** должно быть `use App\Http\ViewComposers\UserinfoComposer;`